# I can't view the waveform in video sequencer

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor, audio

I was working on an animation in Blender, and after that, the button for visualizing the waveform from a mp3 audio disappears. Does anyone know the solution to this problem?
Here are some images:

[image]

I also opened an older file with mp3 audio. The waveform was still visible, but there was no button to activate it.

Thank you all!